# Scraping data with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I want to learn how to scrape a webpage and found an interesting code here:
http://nycdatascience.com/okcupid-scraper/
It doesn't work, but with slight adaptions I could get it to "almost" work, but I'm still stuck at one point.

Could you please help me?

My python code reads:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ('XXXX@gmail.com', 'XXXXX')
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'})
req = session.post('https://www.okcupid.com/login',\
data={'username': 'XXXX', 'password':'XXXX'})

url = 'http://www.okcupid.com/match?filter1=0,48&filter2=2,100,18&filter3=5,2678400&filter4=1,1&locid=0&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=SPECIAL_BLEND&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=30'
page = session.get(url).text
```

Two things are strange:

1) This code works, I do get the html code and I am logged in, so the cookie/session works. But if I wait 5 seconds and call 
    url = 'http://www.okcupid.com/match?filter1=0,48&filter2=2,100,18&filter3=5,2678400&filter4=1,1&locid=0&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=SPECIAL_BLEND&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=30'
    page = session.get(url).text
again, then the page doesn't recognize me anymore. A problem with cookies or the session?

2) I don't get the information I want; the main information I'm interested in is missing in the html code I get:

```
<div class="match_card_text"> <div class="profile_info"> 
<div class="username"> <a class="name">Loading User</a> </div>
```

I get "Loading User" where there's supposed to be the real information. If I open the page in Chrome and look at the html source, there's the information I want in the html code, and no "Loading User". How do I get that information??

Comment: To #2, that information might be loaded in dynamically via javascript. If that is the case, you won't be able to get it using requests. You'll need to use something like Selenium that can control an actual browser.

Comment: Thanks so much. You're right, that did the job! :-D